# OCL constraint on a UML profile in Rational Software Architect 8

Tags: uml, ocl

I'm new to Rational Software Architect 8 and OCL. I defined a profile that consists of two stereotypes, one applied to a class and another one applied to an association. See the figure for more detail.

[image]

Now, I'd like to express a constraint using OCL: if a class has the <> stereotype, then I want all the associations connected to that class to have the *RPAssignment* stereotype. It is worth noting that the classes stereotyped with *Permission* will not have attributes or operations.

I created a small example to test my OCL constraint. Here is the diagram, as well as the relevant bits of the corresponding xmi file, as produced by RSA.

[image: model]

```
    <packageImport xmi:id="_dNGWEwhgEeCzvt5Jj9Wjpg">

  <importedPackage xmi:type="uml:Model" href="pathmap://UML_LIBRARIES/UMLPrimitiveTypes.library.uml#_0"/>

</packageImport>

<packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_sUoV4AhgEeCzvt5Jj9Wjpg" name="ProfileClass"/>

<packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_LkpUwAkoEeCs_vLJf1t9eg" name="Perm1">

  <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_PjkJ8Qk_EeCD2J3jYOsnVw" name="clas" visibility="private" type="_OWO0IAk_EeCD2J3jYOsnVw" association="_PjbAAAk_EeCD2J3jYOsnVw">

    <upperValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralUnlimitedNatural" xmi:id="_PjkJ8wk_EeCD2J3jYOsnVw" value="1"/>

    <lowerValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="_PjkJ8gk_EeCD2J3jYOsnVw" value="1"/>

  </ownedAttribute>

</packagedElement>

<packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_OWO0IAk_EeCD2J3jYOsnVw" name="class1">

  <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_PjbAAQk_EeCD2J3jYOsnVw" name="perm1" visibility="private" type="_LkpUwAkoEeCs_vLJf1t9eg" association="_PjbAAAk_EeCD2J3jYOsnVw">

    <upperValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralUnlimitedNatural" xmi:id="_PjkJ8Ak_EeCD2J3jYOsnVw" value="1"/>

    <lowerValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="_PjbAAgk_EeCD2J3jYOsnVw" value="1"/>

  </ownedAttribute>

</packagedElement>

<packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Association" xmi:id="_PjbAAAk_EeCD2J3jYOsnVw" name="gets" memberEnd="_PjbAAQk_EeCD2J3jYOsnVw _PjkJ8Qk_EeCD2J3jYOsnVw"/>
```

It seemes to me that an association end, when it is flagged as navigable, is a Property, just like an attribute. I tried the following constraint on the *Permission*-stereotyped classes (and a few variations) but it doesn't seem to work correctly. You might have noticed that on the example I created, the association doesn't have the required stereotype, and therefore the verification should fail. However, it succeeds.

```
self.base_Class.getAllAttributes()->forAll(att:Property | att.association.getAppliedStereotype('testProfile::RPAssignment') <> null)
```

Am I missing something trivial here?

Comment: Navigability is irrelevant. All associations are bidirectionally navigable in OCL regardless of navigability declarations. You may need to be clever in regard to using implicit role names and disambiguating them, but full navigability is there in OCL; your tool might not support all the dark corners though.

Comment: Use of getAllAttributes() and getAppliedStereotypes() is not OCL. They are proprietary Java API of the Eclipse UML project that are accessible within Eclipse OCL expressions to workaround the inadequate support for the inadequate specification of stereotype navigation. If you use Papyrus, you can use the Pivot-based OCL that prototypes solutions to many problem in the OCL specification.

Answer (score 0):

You reference the <> stereotype which is not a legal stereotype name. I will use XXX for the sake of a legal name.

Something like the following might work in Papyrus. However it relies on my extrapolation of the very limited hints in regard to stereotype navigation in the UML spec. The OCL spec doesn't mention stereotype at all in this sense.

context XXX
inv: base_Class.allAttributes()->forAll(association <> null implies association.extension_RPAssignment->notEmpty())

NB association is null for simple attributes and navigating the null will cause an invalid evaluation.

If your extension_RPAssignment is at most one, you can use <> null rather than ->notEmpty().

Answer (score -1):

You can not add a constraint in order to create a stereotype. You can only manually create stereotypes on association. The constraints should be used into another context and not for stereotypes creation.
This is my penny to this discussion.

Comment: I'm not trying to create a stereotype here. I want to create an OCL query that will check that all classes associated to the context class are stereotyped with `«Permission»`.